# Как перенести кнопку в другой фаил

Tags: telegram, telebot, разделение-строк

Как сделать так что бы в боте при нажатии кнопки "каки" бот выводил кнопки с файла bb.py ( пока что без ответа просто кнопки)  . Почему то не работает, ни один форум ни ии не помог. надеюсь тут помогут

main.py :

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import coo
import bb

bot = telebot.TeleBot(coo.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    # Создание кнопок
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button1 = types.KeyboardButton('мапа')
    button2 = types.KeyboardButton('каки')
    button3 = types.KeyboardButton('Кнопка 3')

    # Добавление кнопок на клавиатуру
    keyboard.add(button1, button2)

    # Отправка клавиатуры с кнопками
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите опцию:', reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "мапа")
def url(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn_my_site= types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Наш сайт', url='https://')
    btn_gatporn= types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Наш сайт', url='https://')
    markup.add(btn_my_site, btn_gatporn)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нажми на кнопку и перейди на наш сайт.", reply_markup = markup)

# Запускаем бота
bot.polling()
```

bb.py :

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import cook

bot = telebot.TeleBot(cook.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "каки")
def start(message):
    # Создание кнопок
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button1 = types.KeyboardButton('манги4')
    button2 = types.KeyboardButton('каки4')
    button3 = types.KeyboardButton('Кнопка 3')

    # Добавление кнопок на клавиатуру
    keyboard.add(button1)

    # Отправка клавиатуры с кнопками
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите опцию:', reply_markup=keyboard)


if __name__=='__main__': 
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```